# Disable dx aspxbutton

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to set a button's enable/disable based on a checkbox being checked or not. Below is my javascript and asp code, which doesn't work. I am not sure if the function is not called at all, or something is wrong with how I disable the button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function OnChkAgreeChanged(chkAgree) {
    if (document.getElementById"chkAgree").checked)
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").SetEnabled(true);
    else
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").SetEnabled(false);
}
</script>


<asp:checkbox ID="chkAgree" runat="server" 
    Text="blablabla" onchange="javascript:OnChkAgreeChanged(this);"/>


<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
    UseSubmitBehavior="true" AutoPostBack="true" Width="175px" 
    CssClass="submitButton" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" enabled="false">
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

Comment: I think you should use the `disabled` property. `document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;`

Comment: I tried that, but still no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExpress creates a client instance object for each one of it's various controls.  In this case it will create an [ASPxClientButton](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientButtontopic) for btnSubmit.  Since you haven't given btnSubmit a ClientInstanceName, you can access it like so:

```
window.aspxGetControlCollection().elements['<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>'];
```

That means your entire handler function could look something like this:

```
function OnChkAgreeChanged(chkAgree) 
{
    btnSubmit = window.aspxGetControlCollection().elements['<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>'];
    if(!(btnSubmit === null || btnSubmit === undefined)) { btnSubmit.SetEnabed(chkAgree.checked); }
}
```

You could also make your life easier by defining the ClientInstanceName attribute like so:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnSubmit" ClientInstanceName="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
    UseSubmitBehavior="true" AutoPostBack="true" Width="175px" 
    CssClass="submitButton" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" enabled="false">
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

Then, you'd be able to use that directly in your handler:

```
function OnChkAgreeChanged(chkAgree) 
{
    if(!(btnSubmit === null || btnSubmit === undefined)) { btnSubmit.SetEnabed(chkAgree.checked); }
}
```

You'll note that I like to check if that thing is null or not because if you set the display to none in the Code-Behind or otherwise disable it, it's very likely the DevExpress magic/voodoo (pick one) won't emit the JS creating that instance object.

Answer (score 1):

`chkAgree` is an object not a string. You don't have to use `document.getElementById`. Try this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function OnChkAgreeChanged(chkAgree) {
    if (chkAgree.checked)
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = null;
    else
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

Also, in `onchange="javascript:OnChkAgreeChanged(this);"` javascript: may not be required. Pls check ASP documentation.

Comment: I'm trying to disable 'btnSubmit', not 'chkAgree'. But I tried this code to test if disabling 'chkAgree' works, but still no success.

Comment: Thanks, still not working :( 
Not sure how to check if the function is called at all

Comment: did you remove the `javascript:` and check ?

Comment: yes, I did. 
when I inspect the document after running, there is no `onchange` for the checkbox

Comment: I am sorry, add `onclick` for the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery Solution**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#chkAgree').click(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#btnSubmit").prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
            $("#btnSubmit").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Or if you want to do same thing using JavaScript can use solution suggested by mohkhan.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working either. I guess something is wrong with the checkbox definition

Comment: I have upvoted your answer! so, two negatives probably, not by me!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the **ClientInstanceName** and **ClientEnabled** (not the Enabled) properties for this purpose:

```
function OnChkAgreeChanged(chkAgree) {
    var checked = chkAgree.checked;
    btnSubmit.SetEnabled(checked);
}
</script>


<asp:checkbox ID="chkAgree" runat="server" Text="blablabla" onchange="OnChkAgreeChanged(this);"/>

<dx:ASPxButton ... ClientInstanceName="btnSubmit" ClientEnabled="False">
</dx:ASPxButton>
```